# Sodium spectrum and doublet: the 18 T field origin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spin-orbit

The sodium spectrum is dominated by the bright doublet known as the Sodium D-lines at 588.9950 and 589.5924 nanometers. Their origin, as far as we know, is explained by quantum mechanics. The spin orbit energy split between $3p^{3/2}$ and $3p^{1/2}$ levels is given by (experimentally)

$$\Delta E=\mu_Bg_e B\approx 0.0021eV$$

Using the known values of the Bohr magnetic and the $g$-factor of the electron ($g_e\approx 2$), we can derive

$$\mu_Bg_e=5.788\cdot 10^{-5}eV\cdot T^{-1}g_e$$

My question is the following: Can we "explain" the value of the 18 teslas of the B field of the electron in the sodium required to provide the experimentally measured energy shift given by 0.0021eV above?

Details: I mean, I considered the model in which the electron is spinning the orbit, so if thought like a spire

$$B=\dfrac{\mu_0 I}{2R}=\dfrac{\mu_0 Zev}{4\pi R^2}=\dfrac{\mu_0 Zenh}{8\pi^2 R^3}\approx \dfrac{\mu_0 Z^4eh}{8\pi^2 a_B^3n^5}$$

where $I=Q/t=Znev/R$ is the intensity in the "orbit" around the sodium nucleus, $R$ is the orbital radius and I used $v=L/mR=n\hbar$. However, I think this model is wrong since beyond hydrogen ($R_n=a_Bn^2$, $R_n=a_Bn^2/Z$ for hydrogenic atoms). In summary, I was trying to "derive" de 18 T required to explain the 0.0021eV in the spin-orbit 3d(3/2)-3s(1/2), for the sodium doublet, and when I read the model for even the simpler hydrogen, I can not get the numbers "right". But in the case of sodium, I presume the 0.0021eV is not easily derived from theory since I can not see how to find out a right $Z$ such as it gives the 18 T I would need in order to write $\Delta E=(\mu_Bg_e)\times B=0.0021eV$ using the spin-orbit simple formula. Thus, I get things are much more complex but I want to know if I am wrong about the numbers or the model is not right. Maybe do we require to solve the Schrödinger equation with the interaction of electrons? However, the $3s^1$ electron is an outer electron...

I guess electron interactions matter and affect the "effective charge" Z. Indeed, using the numbers even for the hydrogen (Z=1) I get 0.38T and not 0.03 T here (for n=2) in the hyperphysics model: [Spin orbit](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydfin.html#c1)

Comment: I have no idea what's going on in this question: Why are you equating the energy difference to $\mu_B g_e B$? What is the $B$-field supposed to be here, and what does it have to do with the difference between the energy levels?

Comment: @ACuriousMind The spin-orbit coupling can be understood by considering the magnetic field felt by the outer electron. Quoted from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93orbit_interaction#Magnetic_field):
*Although in the rest frame of the nucleus, there is no magnetic field acting on the electron, there is one in the rest frame of the electron*.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch That makes sense, but given that the article you link then goes on to explain how to express that field [in terms of other quantities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93orbit_interaction#Final_energy_shift) I'm still a unsure what the question here is - is it asking for that derivation?